# Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'table' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF

Tags: sql, sql-server, sybase

I have the below error when I execute the following script. What is the error about, and how it can be resolved?

```
Insert table(OperationID,OpDescription,FilterID)
values (20,'Hierachy Update',1)
```

Error:

> Server: Msg 544, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>
> Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'table' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.

Answer (score 681):

You're inserting values for `OperationId` that is an **identity column.**

You can turn on identity insert on the table like this so that you can specify your own identity values.

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT Table1 ON

INSERT INTO Table1
/*Note the column list is REQUIRED here, not optional*/
            (OperationID,
             OpDescription,
             FilterID)
VALUES      (20,
             'Hierachy Update',
             1)

SET IDENTITY_INSERT Table1 OFF
```

Comment: +1 exactly - turn the option to allow explicit inserts **ON**, then insert, then turn the option **OFF** again

Comment: If you really want to add your value to the identity column, this is your answer, but on the other hand, someone have set the column to be incrementing by itself up on insert. In that case the table will keep track of the next free number, and you do not need to generate the OperationID by yourself. The new id can be fetched by SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY().

Comment: good answer, but make sure you know what you are doing. For me it's useful to seed a database with data where the foreign keys need to match up over different tables

Comment: @marc_s Why to turn it OFF again? Can't it just be set ON so that we don't need to set it ON/OFF every time we need to insert a record on the table?

Comment: @UlyssesAlves: this option can **only** be turned on for a single table database-wide - so if you leave it on for one table, you won't be able to ever use it for another table. Also: it's not an option that should be left on - by default, you should let SQL Server handle identity values - this is **only** intended as a last resort measure for very specific cases - not a general-purpose option to leave on or off at your leisure...

Comment: Explanation: An identity is a column with system generated unique ascending integer that is used as a unique identity for the record.  The usual reason is to create a key/number like an invoice number etc that you want to be unique. Writing identity values yourself is fraught, it risks creating creating duplicate values and busting the table integrity.  You want to be clear on what you're up to, not just ramming data into a table because you can.  This might be used for exceptional circumstances like replacing lost data.

Comment: I used this when needing to Drop my table in order to apply some DDL changes after first moving the data into a temp table.  After recreating the same table with the new changes, in order to get the data back in from the temp table in order to maintain those original IDs you have to first set the Identity Insert ON in order to do so.  Now that my data is back in the NEW table with the changes I now have my data back in it exactly as it was but with the new DDL changes and when inserting NEW records SQL Server will handle the rest... as in handle the new keys for the Identity column.

Answer (score 99):

> Simply If you getting this error on SQL server then run this query-

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT tableName ON
```

**This is working only for a single table of database**
e.g  If the table name is `student` then query look like this:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT student ON
```

> If you getting this error on your web application or you using entity framework then first run this query on SQL server and Update your **entity model (`.edmx file`)**  and build your **project** and this error will be resolved

Comment: It was the case in my MVC web app with EF and I just deleted the model from .edmx and re-added (Right Click Update Model From Database) and clean and rebuild the project which then worked for me. Thank you @Umang Patwa

Answer (score 94):

don't put value to OperationID because it will be automatically generated. try this:

```
Insert table(OpDescription,FilterID) values ('Hierachy Update',1)
```

Comment: this is the correct answer if you want automatically generated OperationID

Answer (score 46):

Be very wary of setting IDENTITY_INSERT to ON. This is a poor practice unless the database is in maintenance mode and set to single user. This affects not only your insert, but those of anyone else trying to access the table.

Why are you trying to put a value into an identity field?

Comment: Affects in what way? This is a session level option not a property of the table.

Comment: One time data sync between two databases that you want to maintain relationships.  For example I used it to pull my product schema from one database to another

Comment: @NSjonas, that would be a good use of set Identity _insert table1 ON.  I have seen people who wanted to use this to do something from the application that should be done with a simple insert and allowing the identity to get generated.

Comment: The question is "Could you specify what it is and how it can be resolved?" Your answer is a comment which raises a warning and another question instead of a proper answer that addresses the problem.

Comment: yeah don't insert value in primary key.

Answer (score 31):

In your entity for that table, add the `DatabaseGenerated` attribute above the column for which identity insert is set:

Example:

```
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
public int TaskId { get; set; }
```

Comment: Well, true, but I really wanted an answer for EF :-) Still, it's not appropriate to the OP who may never have used, or perhaps even encountered, EF.

Comment: In any case, the answer is wrong. My entity is already specified with `DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity`, and I still get the error. It's my own fault, I'm putting pseudo-IDs in the new rows to distinguish them from each other on my web page, and I hope simply nulling them before the `insert` is sufficient.

Answer (score 28):

There are basically 2 different ways to INSERT records without having an error:

1) When the IDENTITY_INSERT is set OFF. The PRIMARY KEY **"ID" MUST NOT BE PRESENT**

2) When the IDENTITY_INSERT is set ON. The PRIMARY KEY **"ID" MUST BE PRESENT**

As per the following example from the same Table created with an IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Persons] (    
    ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    LastName VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
    FirstName VARCHAR(40)
);
```

1) In the first example, you can insert new records into the table without getting an error when the IDENTITY_INSERT is OFF. The PRIMARY KEY **"ID" MUST NOT BE PRESENT** from the "INSERT INTO" Statements **and a unique ID value will be added automatically:**.  If the ID is present from the INSERT in this case, you will get the error "Cannot insert explicit value for identify column in table..."

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Persons] OFF;
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Persons] (FirstName,LastName)
VALUES ('JANE','DOE'); 
INSERT INTO Persons (FirstName,LastName) 
VALUES ('JOE','BROWN');
```

**OUTPUT of TABLE [dbo].[Persons] will be:**

```
ID    LastName   FirstName
1     DOE        Jane
2     BROWN      JOE
```

2) In the Second example, you can insert new records into the table without getting an error when the IDENTITY_INSERT is ON. The PRIMARY KEY **"ID" MUST BE PRESENT** from the "INSERT INTO" Statements **as long as the ID value does not already exist**: If the ID is NOT present from the INSERT in this case, you will get the error "Explicit value must be specified for identity column table..."

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Persons] ON;
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Persons] (ID,FirstName,LastName)
VALUES (5,'JOHN','WHITE'); 
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Persons] (ID,FirstName,LastName)
VALUES (3,'JACK','BLACK');
```

**OUTPUT of TABLE [dbo].[Persons] will be:**

```
ID    LastName   FirstName
1     DOE        Jane
2     BROWN      JOE
3     BLACK      JACK
5     WHITE      JOHN
```

Comment: Plus one for actually Explaining how the flag works. Saved my day Superman

Answer (score 17):

Note that if you are closing each line with `;`, the `SET IDENTITY_INSERT mytable ON` command will not hold for the following lines.

i.e.
a query like

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT mytable ON;
INSERT INTO mytable (VoucherID, name) VALUES (1, 'Cole');
```

Gives the error
`Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'mytable' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.`

But a query like this will work:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT mytable ON
INSERT INTO mytable (VoucherID, name) VALUES (1, 'Cole')
SET IDENTITY_INSERT mytable OFF;
```

It seems like the `SET IDENTITY_INSERT` command only holds for a transaction, and the `;` will signify the end of a transaction.

Answer (score 16):

you can simply use This statement for example if your table name is **School**.
Before insertion make sure identity_insert is set to  **ON** and after insert query turn identity_insert  **OFF**

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT School ON
/*
  insert query
  enter code here
*/
SET IDENTITY_INSERT School OFF
```

Comment: Could you expand on your answer a little bit to include an explanation of the command, why it works and what effect it has?

Comment: @gareththegeek yes its for the identity column you have to make sure to make it on to insert data .

Answer (score 10):

everyone comment about SQL, but what happened in EntityFramework? I spent reading the whole post and no one solved EF. So after a few days a found solution:
EF Core  in the context to create the model there is an instruction like this: `modelBuilder.Entity<Cliente>(entity => { entity.Property(e => e.Id).ValueGeneratedNever();`

this produces the error too, solution: you have to change by ValueGeneratedOnAdd() and its works!

Answer (score 8):

If you are using liquibase to update your SQL Server, you are likely trying to insert a record  key into an autoIncrement field. By removing the column from the insert, your script should run.

```
<changeSet id="CREATE_GROUP_TABLE" >
    <createTable tableName="GROUP_D">
        <column name="GROUP_ID" type="INTEGER" autoIncrement="true">
            <constraints primaryKey="true"/>
        </column>
    </createTable>
</changeSet>

<changeSet id="INSERT_UNKNOWN_GROUP" >
    <insert tableName="GROUP_D">    

        <column name="GROUP_ID" valueNumeric="-1"/>
 ...
    </insert>
</changeSet>
```

Answer (score 6):

There is pre-mentioned OperationId in your query which should not be there as it is auto increamented

```
Insert table(OperationID,OpDescription,FilterID)
values (20,'Hierachy Update',1)
```

so your query will be

```
Insert table(OpDescription,FilterID)
values ('Hierachy Update',1)
```

Answer (score 5):

Another situation is to check that the Primary Key is the *same name* as with your classes where the only difference is that your primary key has an 'ID' appended to it or to specify [Key] on primary keys that are not related to how the class is named.

Answer (score 5):

The best solution is to use annotation `GeneratedValue(strategy = ...)`, i.e.

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column ...
private int OperationID;
```

it says, that this column is generated by database using IDENTITY strategy and you don't need to take care of - database will do it.

Answer (score 4):

1. This occurs when you have a (Primary key) column that is not set to Is Identity to true in SQL and you don't pass explicit value thereof during insert. It will take the first row, then you wont be able to insert the second row, the error will pop up. This can be corrected by adding this line of code `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]` in your PrimaryKey column and make sure its set to a data type **int**. If the column is the primary key and is set to IsIDentity to true in SQL there is no need for this line of code `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]`
2. this also occurs when u have a column that is not the primary key, in SQL that is set to Is Identity to true, and in your EF you did not add this line of code `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]`

Comment: Thanks this was the fix iv spent hours looking for.

Answer (score 4):

If you're having this issue while using an sql-server with the sequelize-typescript npm make sure to add `@AutoIncrement` to ID column:

```
  @PrimaryKey
  @AutoIncrement
  @Column
  id!: number;
```

Answer (score 2):

I solved this problem by creating a new object every time I want to add anything to the database.

Answer (score 2):

In my case I was having set another property as key in context for my modelBuilder.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<MyTable>().HasKey(t => t.OtherProp);
```

I had to set the proper id

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<MyTable>().HasKey(t => t.Id);
```

Answer (score 2):

EF Core 3.x

Referencing [Leniel Maccaferri](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62778615/5826992), I had a table with an Autoincrementing attribute called ID(original primary key) and another attribute called Other_ID(The new primary Key). Originally ID was the primary key but then Other_ID needed to be the new Primary key. Since ID was being used in other parts of the application I could not just remove it from Table. [Leniel Maccaferri](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62778615/5826992) solution only worked for me after I added the following snippet:

```
        entity.HasKey(x => x.Other_ID);
        entity.Property(x => x.ID).ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
```

Full Code snippet Below (ApplicationDbContext.cs):

```
  protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
  {
        builder.ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        builder.Entity<tablename>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasKey(x => x.Other_ID);
            entity.Property(x => x.ID).ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
            entity.HasAlternateKey(x => new { x.Other_ID, x.ID });                
        });
        
    }
```

Comment: I have exact same table as yours, what stuck was the old `Id`. To Fix it, simply leave the old `ID` as zero `0`, DB will determine whether to generic a new id, and the error can be fixed without adding the `AlternateKey`

Answer (score 2):

1. First Go to the required table name

Step 2 -> right click on the table name

step 3 --> Select Design

step 4 --> Click on the column name

step 5) go to the column properties then Set **No** to the **Identity Specification**

[**Note:** After insert to the explicit value  if you want you can revert back to identity specification true then again it will generate the value]

if you using SQL server management studio you can use below method

Step 1)
[image]
step 2) [image]

Answer (score 2):

Please try this one =>

```
   [Key]
        [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
        public int dl_no { get;set; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Even if everything was correct, this error can appear if the data type of Identity column is not int or long. I had identity column as decimal, although I was only saving int values (my bad). Changing data type in both database and underlying model fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

Put break point on your [HttpPost] method and check what value is being passed to Id property. If it is other than zero then this error will occur.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31015521)

Answer (score 1):

First thing first...

You need to know why you are getting the error in the first place.

Lets take a simple HttpPost of JSON Data that looks like this:

```
{
"conversationID": 1, 
"senderUserID": 1, 
"receiverUserID": 2,
"message": "I fell for the wrong man!",
"created":"2022-02-14T21:18:11.186Z"
}
```

If you generated your database using Entity framework core while connecting to SQLServer or any other database server, the database automatically takes the responsibility of updating and auto-generating the Key/Unique identifier of the Identity Column, which in most cases is an integer value it auto-increments.

To safely post your data using the in-built conventions which keeps you at a safer end, just remove the ID field from the data you want to send to the database, and let the database engine and ef-core do the heavy lifting which they are designed to do.

So the proper way to post the data would be:

```
{ 
    "senderUserID": 1, 
    "receiverUserID": 2,
    "message": "I fell for the wrong man!",
    "created":"2022-02-14T21:18:11.186Z"
    }
```

You would notice I took out the ConversationID.

You can learn more about entity framework on this website : https://entityframeworkcore.com

I hope you stick more to conventions than configuration in your apps. Knowing how to do things with already proven standards and conventions will save you a lot of working hours.

Answer (score 1):

You can not insert data in  OperationID column when you set `identity increment` for this field.

[image]

Do not enter a value in this field, it will be set automatically.

```
Insert table(OpDescription,FilterID)
values ('Hierachy Update',1)
```

Answer (score 0):

And if you are using Oracle SQL Developer to connect, remember to add /*sqldev:stmt*/

/*sqldev:stmt*/ set identity_insert TABLE on;

Comment: Clearly this is not the case, the question has a "sql-server" tag

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the use for the "Insert Table" is, but if you're just trying to insert some values try:

```
Insert Into [tablename] (OpDescription,FilterID)
values ('Hierachy Update',1);
```

I had the same error message come up, but I think this should work. The ID should auto-increment automatically as long as it's a primary key.

Answer (score 0):

In my CASE I was inserting more character than defined in table.

In My Table column was defined with `nvarchar(3)` and I was passing *more than 3 characters* and same `ERROR` message was coming .

Its not answer but may be in some case problem is similar

Answer (score 0):

im using asp.net core 5.0 and i get that error. i get that error because i was adding another data and triggering the other `.SaveChanges()` method like below :

```
 _unitOfWorkVval.RepositoryVariantValue.Create(variantValue);
 int request = HttpContext.Response.StatusCode;
 if (request == 200)
 {
     int tryCatch = _unitOfWorkCVar.Complete();
     if (tryCatch != 0)
     {
         productVariant.CategoryVariantID = variantValue.CategoryVariantID;
         productVariant.ProductID = variantValue.ProductID;
         productVariant.CreatedDate = DateTime.Now;
         _unitOfWorkProductVariant.RepositoryProductVariant.Create(productVariant);
         _unitOfWorkVval.RepositoryVariantValue.Create(variantValue);
         int request2 = HttpContext.Response.StatusCode;
         if(request==200)
         {
             int tryCatch2=_unitOfWorkProductVariant.Complete();//The point where i get that error
         }///.......
```

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue using Entity Framework with a model like this (I simplified the original code):

```
public class Pipeline
{
  public Pipeline()
  {
     Runs = new HashSet<Run>();
  }

  public int Id {get; set;}
  public ICollection<Run> Runs {get;set;}
}

public class Run
{
  public int Id {get; set;}
  public int RequestId {get; set;}
  public Pipeline Pipeline {get;set;}
}
```

The Run has a many-to-1 relation to the Pipeline (one Pipeline can run multiple times)

In my `RunService` I have injected the DbContex as `context`. The DbContext had a  `Runs` DbSet. I implemented this method in the `RunService`:

```
public async Task<Run> CreateAndInit(int requestId, int pplId)
{
  Pipeline pipeline = await pipelineService.Get(pplId).FirstOrDefaultAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
  Run newRun = new Run {RequestId = requestId, Pipeline = pipeline};
  context.Runs.Add(newRun);
  await context.SaveChangesAsync().ConfigureAwait(false); // got exception in this line
  return newRun;
}
```

As the method executed, I got this exception:

```
Exception has occurred: CLR/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll: 'An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.'
 Inner exceptions found, see $exception in variables window for more details.
 Innermost exception     Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException : Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Pipelines' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.
```

For me, the solution was to separate the creation of the object and relation

```
public async Task<Run> CreateAndInit(int requestId, int pplId)
{
  Pipeline pipeline = await pipelineService.Get(pplId).FirstOrDefaultAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
  Run newRun = new Run {RequestId = requestId};
  context.Runs.Add(newRun);
  newRun.Pipeline = pipeline; // set the relation separately
  await context.SaveChangesAsync().ConfigureAwait(false); // no exception
  return newRun;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was, that I specified the autoincrement ID by myself from the code when I tried to update the records.
After removing the ID property from new record creation, then everything worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue upgrading from Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer 3.1.5 to 6.0.26. I had a query to find a DB object which was then being associated to another DB object. The initial query had .AsNoTracking() so EF was trying to add a new entity. Seemed to work okay with Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer 3.1.5 but when I upgraded to 6.0.26 I was getting the error "Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'TableName' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF."

Answer (score -1):

The problem raised from using non-typed DBContext or DBSet if you using Interface and implement method of savechanges in a generic way

If this is your case I propose to strongly typed DBContex for example

```
MyDBContext.MyEntity.Add(mynewObject)
```

then `.Savechanges` will work

Answer (score -1):

Simply delete the tables that are dragged into your .dbml file and re-drag them again. Then Clean solution>Rebuild solution> Build solution.

Thats what worked for me.

I didnt made the table on my own, I was using VS and SSMS, I followed this link for ASP.NET Identity:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/identity/overview/getting-started/adding-aspnet-identity-to-an-empty-or-existing-web-forms-project