# An explicit value for the identity column in table 'customers' can only be specified when a column list is used and IDENTITY_INSERT is ON

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-express

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table ‘table’ when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334012/cannot-insert-explicit-value-for-identity-column-in-table-table-when-identity)

I am new to SQL. I am trying to write a `INSERT` query in SQL server 2008 Express edition.

The query is :

```
insert into customers
values(201, 'Singh', 'rajnish', '101 bhandup', 'mumbai', 'mp', 33321, 0, null, 123.89, 25.00)
```

But I am getting following error.

> An explicit value for the identity column in table 'customers' can only be specified when a column list is used and IDENTITY_INSERT is ON.

I searched stackoverflow. Found some similar type of questions but unable to understand the explanation. Kindly help me to understand the error and rectify it.

EDIT :

I tried to do :

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT customers ON;
insert into customers
values(201, 'Singh', 'rajnish', '101 bhandup', 'mumbai', 'mp', 33321, 0, null, 123.89, 25.00)
SET IDENTITY_INSERT customers OFF;
```

but again I am getting the same error.

Comment: Either don't insert an explicit value for the identity column or use `SET IDENTITY_INSERT customers ON` to allow you to do so.

Comment: I saw that answer and tried one of the solution mentioned in my edit. But it gave the same error again.

Comment: And you're again not *reading* the error "... when a column list is used **and** IDENTITY_INSERT is ON". You've addressed the second part, but not the first.

Comment: Means I have to use the colmun list?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Try this

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT customers ON
GO
insert into customers(id, ...)
values(201,'Singh','rajnish','101 bhandup','mumbai','mp',33321,0,null,123.89,25.00)
SET IDENTITY_INSERT customers OFF
```

Comment: I tried this query too but again getting same error.

Comment: You need the column list. `insert into customers(id, foo, bar) values (...)`

Comment: Ok, let me try this. Thank you.

Comment: with this work with bulk insert?

Comment: IT does not seem to work: `bulk insert accounts(id,....) from 'c:\sql\src.txt'`

Answer (score 4):

If your first value is the identity column then just remove it, like this:

```
insert into customers
values('Singh','rajnish','101 bhandup','mumbai','mp',33321,0,null,123.89,25.00)
```

Answer (score 2):

When a table is using an identity field it chooses it's own values.  It tracks these values to make sure that it never tries to enter a duplicate and will produce this error if you try to specify your own.

So, in your case either A insert the row without the field that has been marked as an identity field; letting the sql engine pick it's own value for that field. ( that's the whole reason your using an identity field right )

Or, B.  Enable [identity_insert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188059%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) on before running your insert ( if you have a good reason for inserting a specific value as the key ).

You also need to use a [valid insert statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174335%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).  Specify the columns you're inserting as well as the values.