# System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException error even when i am not updating the id column

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework

I am working on a project where I am using Entity framework to manipulate a DB on sql server 2014.
My code is the following:

```
private void BtnAddUser(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var u = new User();
        u.username = txtBoxNewUser.Text;
        u.password = txtBoxNewPass.Text;
        u.rank = cmbBoxRank.GetItemText(this.cmbBoxRank.SelectedItem);
        using (var db = new ProjetPooEntities2())
        {
            db.Users.Add(u);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }

    }
```

Please note that the code runs perfectly but it when i press the Add button to add the created user to the db an error shows on "db.saveChanges()" and it says:

> System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException: 'An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.'
>   And the inner exception is:
>   SqlException: Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'User' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.

I have set the identity column in the db to "id" and it is set to auto-increment by 1 starting from 1.
I have tried searching a lot for a solution but i found nothing.
Any help will be appreciated!!

Comment: Probably you need to set the model that `id` is autoincrement identity field by using `[Key]` and `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]` attributes.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but i am new to sql server and entity framework and i didn't understand where to set these attributs.

Comment: Do I have to create a class for each table in my db and my these attributes in the beginning of the class User? I didn't create  a class for each table that's why I'm asking. Thanks for your help

Comment: Have you using Code First (generate DB based from code) or DB First (generate model classes from DB)? I want to clarify it first before giving answer, since they have different ways to set identity column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose the `User` entity has this structure:

```
public class User
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string username { get; set; }
    public string password { get; set; }
    public string rank { get; set; }
}
```

If **Code First** is used, add `DatabaseGeneratedAttribute` with option `DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity` as this to set `id` as identity autoincrement property:

```
public class User
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int id { get; set; }
    ... // other properties
}
```

However if **Database First** is used, open EDMX model designer, use "Properties" context menu on `id` field and set `StoreGeneratedPattern` to `Identity`:

[image: StoreGeneratedPattern.Identity]

Then, open EDMX file with XML editor and ensure it has `StoreGeneratedPattern="Identity"` on `id` property as shown below:

```
<EntityType Name="User">
    <Key>
        <PropertyRef Name="id" />
    </Key>
    <Property Name="id" Type="int" StoreGeneratedPattern="Identity" Nullable="false" />
</EntityType>
```

If those ways above still won't work thereafter, you can execute `SET IDENTITY_INSERT` query in `DbContext` as this (must be reverting with `StoreGeneratedPattern="None"` in EDMX or `DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)` in Code First to work properly):

```
using (var db = new ProjetPooEntities2())
{
    // taken from /a/31856991
    db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[User] ON");
    db.Users.Add(u);
    db.SaveChanges();
    db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[User] OFF");
}
```

Note that this bottom-most approach here considered not a good practice, since it is possible to allow insertion of duplicate values in certain cases.

Related issues:

[Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'table' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334012/cannot-insert-explicit-value-for-identity-column-in-table-table-when-identity)

[How can I force entity framework to insert identity columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13086006/how-can-i-force-entity-framework-to-insert-identity-columns)

Comment: Thank you so much I put "StoreGeneratedPattern" to "Identity" and it finally worked!!! Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`SET IDENTITY_INSERT sometableWithIdentity ON`

Comment: This is not a good practice while using EF, since it has side effect which allowing duplicate values in identity column (read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21441792/sql-cannot-insert-explicit-value-for-identity-column-in-table-table-when-ident for details).

Comment: @Tetsuya Yamamoto, i removed the link, because it is related to other question. RoyNasr said "I have set the identity column in the db to "id" and it is set to auto-increment by 1 starting from 1", so i think the identity is off on the table.