# Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF - I'm not specifying ID

Tags: c#, sql, .net, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have a pretty standard situation that's been working however upon creating a new database and running (previously working) code, I get the following error:

> Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF

I'm not specifying the ID.

This happens when I do the following:

```
var newFoo = new Foo{
    Name = "test"
}

db.Foos.Add(newFoo);
db.SaveChanges();

public class Foo {
  [Key]
  public int FooId {get; set;}
  public string Name {get; set;}
}
```

Why would this be happening?

Comment: are you using database first?

Comment: Does the set; argument not imply that the FooId will be set? Theoretically it would be passed as NULL? (sorry if this is not correct, I'm new to EF)

Comment: @NtFreX I am using code-first.

Comment: @JacobH no.  This is standard practice.

Comment: Does the previously working code actually define the key like this? `[Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]`

Comment: @Crowcoder - no, I just have [Key] and this has automatically worked up until now.  Do I need to specify that other attribute or is this an indication that something else is going on?  I don't want to go trying things when auto-incrementing was working before, without understanding why it's no longer working.

Comment: I think you are going to have to try something since what you have is not working. I don't get to use EF much but I thought you had to tell it when a key is database generated. Maybe the other code set this via the fluent interface and you just didn't notice because that would likely be done in another file.

Comment: According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43112270/system-data-entity-infrastructure-dbupdateexception-error-even-when-i-am-not-upd?noredirect=1&lq=1) the accepted answer follows what Crowcoder commented about.