# Laravel gives an error when insert data in mssql database

Tags: sql-server, database, laravel, sqlsrv

When i insert data in mssql table it give an error like **SQLSTATE[IMSSP]: The active result for the query contains no fields. (SQL: SET IDENTITY_INSERT TableName ON).** it only happen when primary key is set.

When i remove the query **SET IDENTITY_INSERT TableName ON** it is perfectly work in my system, but if I setup project in another pc and the try to insert data it gives an error like **Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Table_name' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF**.

Thanks in advance

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21441792/sql-cannot-insert-explicit-value-for-identity-column-in-table-table-when-ident/21441948

Comment: Thanks for your reply. this was really helped me. but i was remove the autoincrement column.