# Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'tbl Fingerprint' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, web-services, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to insert data into fingerprint table which has four columns
    - ID (primary key)
    - StudentID (foreign key) linked to student table
    - description
    - Template

But the following error keeps coming up. I can't turn off the IDENTITY for ID as I want it to increment automatically. I also have a student table to store information. What I want to achieve is that after entering student details, I want to copy the studentID that was generated before onto the fingerprint table - StudentID column. the code I have for this is shown below.

```
private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            fgrTemplate template = new fgrTemplate();
            template.StudentID = std.StudentID;
            template.Description = fngDes.Text;
            template.Template = m_StoredTemplate;
            if (upload.InsertTemplate(template))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Student Successfully Added!");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Student Not Successfully Added!");
            }

using (SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO tblFingerprint (StudentID, Description, Template) values ('" + template.StudentID + "' ,'" + template.Description + "' ,@Template)", cn))
```

this is what I have on my web service. However it gives me the error

Comment: Don't add the ID column as part of the Insert. `Insert Table (strcolumn1, strcolumn2) values (1,2)` Table(id int, strcolumn1 varchar(1), strcolumn2 varchar(2))

Comment: You are passing `ID` value in your INSERT statement, `ID` being an identity type should get an auto increment number. See the [linked question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334012/cannot-insert-explicit-value-for-identity-column-in-table-table-when-identity) and also post your related code in the question.

Answer (score 4):

When issuing an `INSERT` statement for a table with an `IDENTITY` column, don't include the identity column in the fields and values list. For example, the following statement would fail:

```
INSERT INTO tbl (ID, StudentID) VALUES (1, 1)
```

but this statement will succeed:

```
INSERT INTO tbl (StudentID) VALUES (1)
```

and insert the next available identity value into the `ID` column.

Now, if you **do** want to insert an actual identity, do this:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT tbl ON
INSERT INTO tbl (ID, StudentID) VALUES (1, 1)
SET IDENTITY_INSERT tbl OFF
```

Comment: @user3144368, please edit your **question** with the code and delete this comment.