# Cannot insert explicit

Tags: sql, sql-server

Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Tbl_UserGroup' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.

I got the error message: `Cannot insert explicit` while saving,
but using sql command line the value got inserted, the problem just is using the form.
What is the possible solution?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'table' when IDENTITY\_INSERT is set to OFF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334012/cannot-insert-explicit-value-for-identity-column-in-table-table-when-identity)

Answer (score 2):

You need to set `identity insert ON` if you are going to `explicitly` insert values into identity column

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT table  ON 

--Insert statement 

SET IDENTITY_INSERT table  OFF
```

Comment: Please consider voting to close on questions that have already been answered on this site.