# Entity Framework does not allow to insert a column in localdb (Mvc 4- C#)

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I created an ASP.NET MVC 4 application using Visual Studio 2012. The application is just normal and I did nothing fancy. Indeed no-coding at all.

(The default app seems to be using Localdb, simple membership implemented using `AccountController`)

I ran the application, clicked `Register` and created a user.

Then, I went to the `Server Explorer`, navigated to the table `UserProfile`, right-clicked the table and clicked `New Query`

And executed this query

```
insert into dbo.UserProfile (UserId,UserName) 
values ("test", "test")
```

This results in

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid column name 'test'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid column name 'test'.

Note: I also executed `Enable-Migrations` using `Package Manager Console` but the error message still comes.

Any ideas why ?

***Update 1:***

According to @CodeCaster's answer, I executed with ['] single quotes and it seems to be working fine.

However, now I get

> Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'UserProfile' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF

Comment: How is this related to Entity Framework?

Comment: If `UserId` is an **Identity** column, then you ought **not** to insert any values into it - SQL Server will do that for you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use single quotes in SQL... `('test', 'test')`

Comment: Thanks a lot, this seems to be good. However, I get an error saying `Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'UserProfile' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.` Any ideas why ?

Comment: [Try the search](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334012/cannot-insert-explicit-value-for-identity-column-in-table-table-when-identity).

Comment: @CodeCaster you are so fast :)

Comment: @CodeCaster: Great find. Thanks a lot CodeCaster. In nutshell, I was trying to insert an Id but seems like `Sql` will automatically create the `Id`. However, the question that is bugging me is `In MVC 4 EF, how do one assign roles easily without writing Sql statements to do it ? Is there some easy method` ?

Comment: Using the [Web Site Administration Tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ssa0wsyf(v=vs.140).aspx).

Comment: @CodeCaster: Awesome. I will `google` further. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this code

```
insert into dbo.UserProfile (UserId,UserName) values ('test','test')
```

you are using `"` instead of `'` change `"test"` to `'test'`

Single quotes are used to indicate the beginning and end of a string in SQL. Double quotes generally not using in SQL

Comment: Thank you Arun. However, Is it a `rule-syntax` that we should only use `Single quotes while inserting to a table?` . Any ideas about the doc ?

Comment: Got the answer on `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks`