# How to clone an entity in Entity Framework Core?

Tags: entity-framework

I'm trying to clone an entity using the SetValues method but I get the following error :

*The instance of entity type 'TariffPeriod' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'Id'} is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached.*

Here is the code :

```
var period2 = _tariffRepository.GetPeriodFull(period.GUID);
var period3 = new TariffPeriod();
_appDbContext.TariffPeriods.Add(period3);
_appDbContext.Entry(period3).CurrentValues.SetValues(period2);
```

I see that the error is due to the value of the primary key being copied into the new entity. So, how do I copy the values without the key?

Thanks for your help
Eric

Comment: Can you detach period2? And then set its Id to that of period3 between the Add and the SetValue?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can try getting a clone of the period2 data and modify the Id before assigning to period3

```
var values = db.Entry(period2).CurrentValues.Clone();
values["Id"] = 0;
db.Entry(period3).CurrentValues.SetValues(values);
```

Answer (score 16):

### Solution 1

This is my solution based on @grek40's solution with casting added to avoid string literals and allow for future refactoring.

`_appDbContext` helper method:

```cs
    public TEntity DetachedClone<TEntity>(TEntity entity) where TEntity : class
            => Entry(entity).CurrentValues.Clone().ToObject() as TEntity;
```

For your answer:

```cs
    var period2 = _tariffRepository.GetPeriodFull(period.GUID);
    var period3 = _appDbContext.DetachedClone(period2);
    _appDbContext.TariffPeriods.Add(period3);
```

---

### Solution 2

You can use a simple JSON deep clone function as well. Works like charm. I prefer this method because the first solution involves attaching the entry first using `.Entry()` and that could be not desirable

```cs
    public static T Clone<T>(T source)
    {
        var serialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(source);
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(serialized);
    }
```

(ﾉ◕ヮ◕)ﾉ*✲ﾟ*｡⋆

Comment: You can just use nameof() if you're that worried about string literals.

Answer (score 6):

Copy the values from the old period to the new period, then set properties with unique values (in this case, the primary key), and lastly add the entity to the DbContext.

```
var period2 = _tariffRepository.GetPeriodFull(period.GUID);
var period3 = new TariffPeriod();
_appDbContext.Entry(period3).CurrentValues.SetValues(period2);
period3.Id = 0;
_appDbContext.TariffPeriods.Add(period3);
```

Answer (score 0):

In EF Core 8 I'm just getting the entity with `AsNoTracking`, setting it's Id to 0 and inserting it again

```
var myEntity = await _dbContext.MyEntities
    .AsNoTracking()
    .SingleOrDefaultAsync(e => e.EventStart.Date == DateTime.UtcNow.Date);

myEntity.Id = 0;

await _dbContext.MyEntities.AddAsync(myEntity);
await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Comment: Can confirm this works in EF Core 3.  See [EntityFramework Core - Copying an entity and placing it back into the database](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78226624)