# Clone entity with multiple children levels cause PK Violation

Tags: c#, .net, postgresql, entity-framework-core

I am using Postgresql

I have an application that uses EF Core as its data layer and now I need to create a process that will clone a row in a table, but it will also clone all its children with their respective children and so on.

I do query the item that I can to clone with the multiple `.Include()` and `.ThenInclude()` calls, and that works fine, but when I try to insert the new item to the database I get a PK violation on the children tables.

I've tried zeroing the PK column on the item and all the children, but that didn't make any difference.

If I check the ChangeTracker of the DbContext, I can see that all the Ids are set to `int.MinValue`.

Am I doing something obviously wrong?

```cs
var clone = _context
    .Owners
    .Include(s => s.Items)
    .ThenInclude(p => p.Processes)
    .ThenInclude(l => l.Conditions)
    .ThenInclude(c => c.Actions)
    .ThenInclude(a => a.Mapping)
    .AsNoTracking()
    .First(c => c.Id == id);

if (clone == null)
    return null;

clone.Id = 0;
clone.Description = $"Clone of {clone.Description}";
// Zero out all the ids ...

_context.Owners.Add(clone);
_context.SaveChanges();

return clone;
```

Comment: you could try to detach the entity `_context.Entry(clone).State = EntityState.Detached;` maybe even for all included data.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45914736/how-to-clone-an-entity-in-entity-framework-core

Comment: I tried both solutions.
Detaching all the entities and also using the `DettachedClone` mentioned in the link above, but I still always get the PK Violation already in the first child level.