# Clone an object (EF entity) in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-3.0, c#-8.0

Using C# 8 e ASP.NET Core I have the following:

```
  Context context = new Context();

  Post post1 = new Post {
    Enabled = true,
    Title = "Some title"
  };

  Post post2 = post1;
  post2.Enabled = false;

  context.Posts.Add(post1);
  context.Posts.Add(post2);
```

On `context`, which is an EF DBContext, I get only one post (`post2`);

Maybe I am wrong but I think I should Copy / Clone post1 to define post2.

Am I right? How to do this?

Comment: You create only one post. What else do you expect ? Yes you can create a second one, or Clone the first one - as you like. `post2 = new Post { Title = post1.Title };`

Comment: marking this is a duplicate seems a little aggressive.  Plus my full answer below gives you an EF model clone in 1/100th of the code of the accepted answer that has been linked as duplicated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

because of this line:

```
Post post2 = post1;
```

`post1` and `post2` are the same object, and EF will treat them as the same object.

You should have some clone to create a totally new post, like:

```
Post post2 = new Post()
{
   Title = post1.Title,
   Enabled = false;
};
```

Possible other way to clone without setting individual properties (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43596746/29798) for more detail)

```
Post post2 = (Post) context.Entry(post1).CurrentValues.ToObject();
```

Comment: Sure, but I would like to avoid that as Post has many properties not only the two ones that I mentioned. So I was looking for a better way to clone it.

Comment: See my edit, I found another answer on SO with code to do a deep copy using EF models

Comment: Worked! Copy all object members/properties using: Post post2 = (Post) context.Entry(post1).CurrentValues.ToObject(); Faster when using await context.SaveChangesAsync();

Answer (score 0):

since `class` is `ReferenceType`, so you only get a `post2` with `Enabled` as `false`, which is actually `post1`, they are same thing by your code, `post1 === post2`.

I believe your real class contains more properties than example. 
so if you want to a simple `Clone`, you can use `var post2 = (Post)post1.Clone();`, but normaly we make `deep clone` in complex objects, you can follow this post:
[Deep cloning objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78536/deep-cloning-objects)