# Code igniter update failing with 'Cannot insert explicit value for identity column'

Tags: php, sql-server, codeigniter

The error that I am getting is:

Error Number: 23000/544

> [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Cannot insert
>   explicit value for identity column in table 'audit_domain' when
>   IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.

```
UPDATE "domain" SET "domain_acronym" = 'RM', "domain" = Resource Management', "reference_name" = 'Resource Mgmt' WHERE "id" = '1'
```

The code that I am using:

```
$updatedata['domain_acronym'] = $this->postdata['domain_acronym'];
$updatedata['domain_name'] = $this->postdata['domain_name'];
$updatedata['reference_name'] = $this->postdata['reference_name'];

$this->db->where($pk, $pkValue);
$this->db->update('domains', $updatedata);
```

The domain table has the primary key of Id and the audit table doesn't have any primary key set. I have been trying to fix this for a couple of days now so any pointers on how to debug/fix it would be really appreciated.

Comment: Check this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334012/cannot-insert-explicit-value-for-identity-column-in-table-table-when-identity?rq=1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'table' when IDENTITY\_INSERT is set to OFF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334012/cannot-insert-explicit-value-for-identity-column-in-table-table-when-identity)

Answer (score 0):

Run this query

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT YourtableName ON
```

Comment: it works when i run the SQL from sql manager. Its $this->db->update('domains', $updatedata) where it fails

Answer (score 0):

Try in this way

```
$domain_acronym = $this->postdata['domain_acronym'];
$domain_name = $this->postdata['domain_name'];
$reference_name = $this->postdata['reference_name'];

$query="update table_name set col_name1='$domain_acronym',col_name2='$domain_name ',col_name3='$reference_name ' where id=$pkValue";

$this-db->query($query);
```

Comment: A note: this advice is prone to SQL Injection vulnerability.

Comment: codeigniter provide Cross-site request forgery (CSRF) Security Class so we use this class for Security

Comment: 1. It's not me asked a question but someone else. I just made a comment. 2. CSRF has nothing to do with sql injections 3. People tend to copy paste from stackoverflow. So if an answer contains a security vulnerability be sure it also will be ported to their code.