# Hibernate insert failing when embedded key contains identity column on SQL Server

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate, jpa, composite-id

I'm trying to map an entity with hibernate, but with SQL Server, I am not able to proceed.

Following are the details.

SQL Server Entity

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[BOOK_EMBEDDED](
  [row_id] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
  [group_no] [int]                NOT NULL,
  [book_name] [varchar](255)      NULL,
  CONSTRAINT [PK_BOOK_EMBEDDED] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
  [group_no] ASC,
  [row_id] ASC
) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF,
        STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF,
        IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF,
        ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON,
        ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

=============================

**The embedded key**

```java
@Embeddable 
public class EmbeddedKey implements Serializable { 
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L; 

    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY) 
    @Column(name = "row_id") 
    private Long rowId; 

    @Column(name = "group_no") 
    private int groupNo; 

    public Long getRowId() { 
        return rowId; 
    } 

    public void setRowId(Long rowId) { 
        this.rowId = rowId; 
    } 

    public static long getSerialversionuid() { 
        return serialVersionUID; 
    } 

    @Override 
    public int hashCode() { 
        final int prime = 31; 
        int result = 1; 

        result = (int) (prime * result + rowId); 
        result = prime * result + groupNo; 

        return result; 
    } 

    @Override 
    public boolean equals(Object obj) { 
        if (this == obj) 
            return true; 

        if (obj == null) 
            return false; 

        if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) 
            return false; 

        EmbeddedKey other = (EmbeddedKey) obj; 

        if (rowId != other.rowId) 
            return false; 

        if (groupNo != other.groupNo) 
            return false; 

        return true; 
    } 

    @Override 
    public String toString() { 
        return this.getRowId() + "  " + this.getGroupNo() + " "; 
    } 
 
    public int getGroupNo() { 
        return groupNo; 
    } 
 
    public void setGroupNo(int groupNo) { 
        this.groupNo = groupNo; 
    } 
}
```

**The Entity**

```java
@Entity(name = "BOOK_EMBEDDED") 
public class BookMySQL implements Serializable { 
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L; 

    @Column(name = "BOOK_NAME") 
    private String book_Name; 

    @EmbeddedId 
    private EmbeddedKey key; 

    public BookMySQL() { 
    } 

    public String getBook_Name() { 
        return book_Name; 
    } 

    public void setBook_Name(String book_Name) { 
        this.book_Name = book_Name; 
    } 

    public static long getSerialversionuid() { 
        return serialVersionUID; 
    } 

    public EmbeddedKey getKey() { 
        return key; 
    } 

    public void setKey(EmbeddedKey key) { 
        this.key = key; 
    } 

    @Override 
    public String toString() { 
        return this.getKey().toString() + "  " + this.getBook_Name(); 
    } 
}
```

**Entity Manager class**

```java
public class LocalEntityManager { 
    private static EntityManagerFactory emf; 
    private static EntityManager em; 

    private LocalEntityManager() { 
    } 

    public static EntityManager getEntityManger() { 
        if (emf == null) { 
            synchronized (LocalEntityManager.class) { 
                if (emf == null) { 
                    emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("BookEntities"); 
                    em = emf.createEntityManager(); 
                } 
            } 
        } 

        return em; 
    } 
}
```

**Book Service**

```java
public class MySQLBookService { 

    public Long persistBook(String bookName) { 
        EmbeddedKey key = new EmbeddedKey(); 
        key.setGroupNo(1); 

        BookMySQL book = new BookMySQL(); 
        book.setBook_Name(bookName); 
        book.setKey(key); 

        EntityManager em = LocalEntityManager.getEntityManger(); 
        EntityTransaction tx = em.getTransaction(); 

        tx.begin(); 
        em.persist(book); 
        tx.commit(); 

        em.close(); 

        return book.getKey().getRowId(); 
    } 

    public BookMySQL findBook(int bookId) { 
        EntityManager em = LocalEntityManager.getEntityManger();
 
        EmbeddedKey key = new EmbeddedKey(); 
        key.setGroupNo(1); 
        key.setRowId(1L); 

        BookMySQL bookMySQL = em.find(BookMySQL.class, key); 

        System.out.println(bookMySQL); 

        return bookMySQL; 
    } 

    public static void main(String... args) { 
        MySQLBookService bookService = new MySQLBookService(); 
        // bookService.findBook(1); 
        bookService.persistBook("Lord of the rings"); 
    } 
}
```

The problem is I cannot use a sequence and by executing this
findBook always works and persist fails with error.

```
ERROR: Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'BOOK_EMBEDDED' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: could Yoy format code according to SO rules?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The only way to make it work is to overwrite the `SQLInsert` and trick Hibernate which expects to set the identifier column. This can be done if you provide your own custom INSERT statement so that, instead of setting the `rowId` to null, you set the version instead:

```
@Entity(name = "BOOK_EMBEDDED")
@SQLInsert( sql = "insert into BOOK_EMBEDDED (BOOK_NAME, group_no, version) values (?, ?, ?)")
public static class Book implements Serializable {

    @EmbeddedId
    private EmbeddedKey key;

    @Column(name = "BOOK_NAME")
    private String bookName;

    @Version
    @Column(insertable = false)
    private Integer version;

    public EmbeddedKey getKey() {
        return key;
    }

    public void setKey(EmbeddedKey key) {
        this.key = key;
    }

    public String getBookName() {
        return bookName;
    }

    public void setBookName(String bookName) {
        this.bookName = bookName;
    }
}
```

With this change in place, you run the following test:

```
doInJPA(entityManager -> {

    EmbeddedKey key = new EmbeddedKey();
    key.setGroupNo(1);

    Book book = new Book();
    book.setBookName( "High-Performance Java Persistence");

    book.setKey(key);

    entityManager.persist(book);
});

doInJPA(entityManager -> {
    EmbeddedKey key = new EmbeddedKey();

    key.setGroupNo(1);
    key.setRowId(1L);

    Book book = entityManager.find(Book.class, key);
    assertEquals( "High-Performance Java Persistence", book.getBookName() );
});
```

And Hibernate will generate the right SQL statements:

```
Query:["insert into BOOK_EMBEDDED (BOOK_NAME, group_no, version) values (?, ?, ?)"], Params:[(High-Performance Java Persistence, 1, NULL(BIGINT))]

Query:["select compositei0_.group_no as group_no1_0_0_, compositei0_.row_id as row_id2_0_0_, compositei0_.BOOK_NAME as BOOK_NAM3_0_0_, compositei0_.version as version4_0_0_ from BOOK_EMBEDDED compositei0_ where compositei0_.group_no=? and compositei0_.row_id=?"], Params:[(1, 1)]
```

The test is available on [GitHub](https://github.com/vladmihalcea/high-performance-java-persistence/blob/1fcd846f5fb6f356e4509218f9bd5dd38127b7fe/core/src/test/java/com/vladmihalcea/book/hpjp/hibernate/identifier/composite/CompositeIdGeneratedIdClassTest.java).

Comment: Interesting, but actually hibernate forum (https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=1006818) suggest that can't be done. Does it work with venilla hibernate, I have tried with only hibernate (no JPA)  but could not able to achieve.. if you want, I can post error

Comment: That forum answer is from 2010, mine is from 2017 and has a test case that works just fine which you can find on GitHub. Just fork my High-Performance Java Persistence book repository and run the test.

Comment: yes. sure, I did look into it. I will try with it and update you. Again, can I expect it work with **vanilla(no jpa)** hibernate?

Comment: You can make all tests in that repository run in Hibernate mode as well. Take a look on the AbstractTest and check the native bootstrap.

Comment: Sure @Vlad Mihalcea, Thanks .. I will try to workout today.

Comment: This workaround doesn't seem to work properly, at least not with Hibernate 5.2.10.Final. I'm getting errors like: "Parameter index out of range (29 > number of parameters, which is 28)". Hibernate clearly adds the id to the query parameters, which is visible in debug mode. Insertable = false on the id column in the embeddable doesn't change a thing.

Comment: OK, I see what you did there - you've added a dummy column called "version" which will always be null. Not very clean, but it works I guess. Calling a procedure that would ignore the extra argument could be a cleaner solution.

Comment: That's not a dummy column. That's the optimistic locking version column.

Comment: If someone is not using optimistic locking, he will need a dummy column (or perhaps a procedure call will work). The fact that you've annotated it as a @Version column in your example doesn't change that. Also, it seems this workaround doesn't work combined with a persist cascade - Hibernate puts null/zero to the FK column instead of the identity generated identifier of the parent entity (maybe it needs another workaround, which would be very Hibernatesque :)). Anyway I'd advise proceeding with caution.

Comment: more details is here [hear](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-map-a-composite-identifier-using-an-automatically-generatedvalue-with-jpa-and-hibernate/)

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the identity_insert to ON to make it work.

Check this post - [How to set IDENTITY_INSERT](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1334032/2065083)

So run below command:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT BOOK_EMBEDDED ON
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply delete & remove the EmbeddedKey class and add the fields to your entity.

```java
import java.io.*;
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity(name = "Book")
@Table(name = "book")
public class Book implements Serializable
{

  @Id
  @Basic(optional = false)
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Column(name = "registration_number")
  private Long registrationNumber;

  @Column(name = "publisher_id")
  private Integer publisherId;

  @Column(name = "title")
  private String title;

  //Getters and setters omitted for brevity
}
```

```sql
CREATE TABLE book (
        publisher_id INT NOT NULL,
        registration_number BIGINT IDENTITY NOT NULL,
        title VARCHAR(255),
        PRIMARY KEY (publisher_id, registration_number)
    )
```