# How to Generate a Composite Key With Two Auto-Increment Fields and Reset the Second When the First Changes

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa

I need to define an `Entity` identified by a composite key, and this composite key shall be generated automatically. Here is the composite key...

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class PK implements Serializable {

    private UUID id;
    private int version;

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        PK pk = (PK) o;
        return Objects.equals(id, pk.id) && Objects.equals(version, pk.version);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(id, version);
    }
}
```

... end here the entity:

```
@Getter
@Entity
@Table(name = "questionnaire")
@IdClass(PK.class)
public class Questionnaire {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private UUID id;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @Column(name = "version", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    @NotNull
    private int version;

    @Column(name = "definition")
    @Lob
    @Setter
    private String definition;
}
```

The composite key consists of fields `id` and  `version`, where `id` shall contain an auto-generated UUID whereas `version` shall be an auto-incremented integer. The problem is that `version` shall start from `1` for every new entity:

```
+--------------------------------------+---------+------------+
|                                   ID | VERSION | DEFINITION |
+--------------------------------------+---------+------------+
| 250d7ef2-fb84-4a61-9ad4-bff3d2fa8db7 |       1 | {CLOB}     |
| 250d7ef2-fb84-4a61-9ad4-bff3d2fa8db7 |       2 | {CLOB}     |
| 250d7ef2-fb84-4a61-9ad4-bff3d2fa8db7 |       3 | {CLOB}     |
| 7102cf45-1e4b-4e3f-b8e9-ab90dd597f21 |       1 | {CLOB}     |
| 7102cf45-1e4b-4e3f-b8e9-ab90dd597f21 |       2 | {CLOB}     |
| 7102cf45-1e4b-4e3f-b8e9-ab90dd597f21 |       3 | {CLOB}     |
+--------------------------------------+---------+------------+
```

In the table above, there are 2 entities (`250d7ef2-fb84-4a61-9ad4-bff3d2fa8db7` and `7102cf45-1e4b-4e3f-b8e9-ab90dd597f21`), each with 3 versions.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53595226/how-to-autoincrement-an-id-in-a-composite-primary-key-in-hibernate

Comment: No... in the answer provided they are setting the second field in the key manually...