# How to enable Is identity in entity framework?

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, entity-framework

[image]

I am trying to make TransactionId increased using Is Identity in my code. But it shows this following error :

> SqlException: Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in
>   table 'TransactionHistories' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.

I tried to put `[DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]` syntax. But it didn't work.

```
public partial class TransactionHistories
    {
        [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int TransactionId { get; set; }

        public DateTime? TransactionDate { get; set; }
        public long? CheckingAccountNumber { get; set; }
        public long? SavingAccountNumber { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Transffered Amount")]
        public decimal? Amount { get; set; }
        public decimal? Transactionfee { get; set; }
        public long? TransactionTypeId { get; set; }
    }
```

---

```
            TransactionHistories = new TransactionHistories();
            TransactionTypes = new TransactionTypes();

            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return Page();
            }

            SavingAccounts.Balance = SavingAccounts.Balance - Amount;
            CheckingAccounts.Balance = CheckingAccounts.Balance + Amount;

            //TransactionHistories.TransactionId = TransactionHistories.TransactionId + 1;
            TransactionHistories.TransactionDate = DateTime.Now;
            TransactionHistories.CheckingAccountNumber = CheckingAccounts.CheckingAccountNumber;
            TransactionHistories.SavingAccountNumber = SavingAccounts.SavingAccountNumber;
            TransactionHistories.Amount = Amount;
            TransactionHistories.Transactionfee = 0;
            TransactionHistories.TransactionType = "SavingToChecking";
```

Above is my model class and TransactionId is primary key which is the value I am trying to make it increase by 1 using Is Identity. How can I make this work? Please give me any advice and help.

Comment: Try adding `[key]` attribute in addition to the DatabaseGenerateOption or change the field to classname + Id (TransactionHistoriesId)

Comment: I tried to put [key] attribute but still not working. Btw changing class name would matter for this issue?

Comment: Do you have access to the database and if so is it SQL? and if that is also the case do you have SSMS installed? also you have a typo in your Amount display name

Comment: I am using SSMS and retrieved data form SSMS server into visual studio when I created the data models.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'table' when IDENTITY\_INSERT is set to OFF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334012/cannot-insert-explicit-value-for-identity-column-in-table-table-when-identity)

Comment: However you are inserting, make sure you do not supply the ID. let the database generate it.

Comment: I put up my code.. I am not sure whether I am supplying ID myself.

Comment: I put the values into properties in TransactionHistories except id value.

Answer (score -1):

[Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'table' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334012/cannot-insert-explicit-value-for-identity-column-in-table-table-when-identity)

> SET IDENTITY_INSERT "table" ON

Comment: Could you mention where I should exactly go to change that option?

Comment: You pretty much only want to do that when seeding the database. It is irresponsible to tell someone to turn identity insert on.

Comment: @Gideok Seong in your sql ui ,you should write this command to command line

Comment: Here is Gideok want to add auto-increment column in database and you telling it is seeding database and it is irresponsible. We are focus on problems and this problem will be fix this solution 'SET IDENTİTY_INSERT "table" ON'