# Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table when identity insert is set to off

Tags: c#, sql-server, ef-core-2.2

I tried filling in a table I generated using EF Core with values through Microsoft SQL Management Studio, since the list was predefined and wouldn't require editing in the future. I got the error I wrote in the title inside the console of SSMS.

I managed to resolve the issue by writing `SET IDENTITY_INSERT Countries ON` above the script that would insert all the values.

This problem seems to have to do with the primary key attribute.

My question is: how do I fix this using EF Core methods, instead of the `SET IDENTITY_INSERT ON` SQL command, and what exactly is the issue?

Problem table:

```cs
public class Country
{
    public string Code { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string LongName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: *"This problem seems to have to do with the primary key attribute."* It's nothing to do with the primary Key, it's to do with the `IDENTITY` property. You cannot insert into a column with the `IDENTITY` property unless you use `SET IDENTITY_INSERT ON`. The fact that you *want* to always insert into the column infers that the column should not have the `IDENTITY` property.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'table' when IDENTITY\_INSERT is set to OFF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334012/cannot-insert-explicit-value-for-identity-column-in-table-table-when-identity)

Comment: @Larnu what does the identity property do? Also, which one of my EF Core props would be it?

Comment: [CREATE TABLE (Transact-SQL) IDENTITY (Property)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql-identity-property?view=sql-server-ver15) @NAlexP .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to apply annotation attribute to Id and it will do the job

```
[DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
public int Id { get; set; }
```

Comment: What does that annotation actually mean, though?

Comment: It is .net attributes that can be applied on an entity property to override default convention