# ef core insert list of entity with navigation property

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have Model.

```
public class Lessee
    {
        public long Id { get; set; }

        public string LesseeName { get; set; }

        public bool? LogicalDeleteIn { get; set; }
    }
```

and another model with a navigation property to the first.

```
  public class RevenueReceived
    {
        public long Id { get; set; }

        ...

        public Lessee Lessee { get; set; }

    }
```

I then populate a list of Lessees and insert and that works fine.

```
   public List<Lessee> InsertLessees(List<Lessee> lessees)
        {
            using (var ctx = new DataContext())
            {
                ctx.Lessees.AddRange(lessees);
                ctx.SaveChanges();
                return lessees;
            }
        }
```

I then create a list of RevenueReceived and add the corresponding Lessee.

```
public List<RevenueReceived> GetRevenueReceived(List<Lessee> lessees)
        {
            List<RevenueReceived> retval = new List<RevenueReceived>();
            using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(accessConnectionString))
            using (OleDbCommand Command = new OleDbCommand(" SELECT * from tblRevenueReceived", con))
            {
                con.Open();
                OleDbDataReader DB_Reader = Command.ExecuteReader();
                while (DB_Reader.Read())
                {
                    string lesseeName = DB_Reader.IsDBNull(DB_Reader.GetOrdinal("Company")) ? null : DB_Reader.GetString(DB_Reader.GetOrdinal("Company"));

                        retval.Add(new RevenueReceived
                    {
                        Id = 0,
                        ...
                        Lessee = string.IsNullOrEmpty(lesseeName) ? null :  lessees.FirstOrDefault(x => x.LesseeName == lesseeName)
                    }); 
                }
            }
            return retval;
        }
```

and finally I try and save the list of revenue received.

```
public void InsertRevenuesReceived(List<RevenueReceived> revenuesReceived)
        {
            using (var ctx = new DataContext())
            {
                ctx.RevenueReceived.AddRange(revenuesReceived);
                ctx.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
```

and I am receiving  the error below. I am a bit confused why it is trying to insert into the lessees table again.  is there a way to get to just insert the primary key but not have it try to insert back into lessees again?

> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException   HResult=0x80131500
>   Message=An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner
>   exception for details.
>   Source=Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational   StackTrace:    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.ReaderModificationCommandBatch.Execute(IRelationalConnection
>   connection)    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.Execute(DbContext
>   _, ValueTuple`2 parameters)    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.Execute[TState,TResult](TState
>   state, Func`3 operation, Func`3 verifySucceeded)    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.Execute(IEnumerable`1
>   commandBatches, IRelationalConnection connection)    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalDatabase.SaveChanges(IList`1
>   entries)    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChanges(IList`1
>   entriesToSave)    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChanges(Boolean
>   acceptAllChangesOnSuccess)    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SaveChanges(Boolean
>   acceptAllChangesOnSuccess)    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SaveChanges()    at
>   accessdataimport.DataImportService.InsertRevenuesReceived(List`1
>   revenuesReceived) in
>   C:\Users\c-bdelling\source\repos\Minerals\accessdataimport\DataImportService.cs:line
>   100    at accessdataimport.Program.Main(String[] args) in
>   C:\Users\c-bdelling\source\repos\Minerals\accessdataimport\Program.cs:line
>   29
>
> Inner Exception 1: SqlException: Cannot insert explicit value for
>   identity column in table 'Lessees' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'table' when IDENTITY\_INSERT is set to OFF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334012/cannot-insert-explicit-value-for-identity-column-in-table-table-when-identity)

Comment: no I don't think so.  I believe my problem is that it is trying to insert into the child table (Lessee) and I don't want it to.  (as I already have inserted into Lessee)

Comment: Do you have an FK property for Lessee on your `RevenueReceived` model? e.g. `public long Lessee_Id { get; set; }`

Comment: Yeah, I don't think you need to set the Lessee property of each RevenueReceived object, just set the LesseeId instead

Comment: no I was just doing it implicitly. but I could add one, I was just reading up on that. so I would update the fk and then set the child to unchanged?

Comment: thanks John I think I'll give that a shot

Comment: Just setting the FK should work - If you still face the same issue, let us know.

Comment: It looks like EF is not aware of lessee's existence, so it cannot do its "magic update". You can try to 1) Refactor your code and load lessee directly from the DB before adding into RevenueReceived; or 2) Attach the lessee entity into the DB Context inside the while loop.