# Spark write Dataframe to SQL Server Table with Insert Identity On

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a Spark Dataframe that I want to push to an SQL table on a remote server. The table has an Id column that is set as an identity column. The Dataframe I want to push also has as Id column, and I want to use those Ids in the SQL table, without removing the identity option for the column.

I write the dataframe like this:

```
df.write.format("jdbc") \
      .mode(mode) \
      .option("url", jdbc_url) \
      .option("dbtable", table_name) \
      .option("user", jdbc_username) \
      .option("password", jdbc_password) \
      .option("driver", "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver") \
      .save()
```

But I get the following response:

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 41.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 41.0 (TID 41, 10.1.0.4, executor 0): java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table &#39Table&#39; when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.
```

I have tried to add a query to the writing like:

```
query = f"SET IDENTITY_INSERT Table ON;"
df.write.format("jdbc") \
      .mode(mode) \
      .option("url", jdbc_url) \
      .option("query", query) \
      .option("dbtable", table_name) \
      .option("user", jdbc_username) \
      .option("password", jdbc_password) \
      .option("driver", "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver") \
      .save()
```

But that just throws an SQL syntax error:

```
IllegalArgumentException: Both 'dbtable' and 'query' can not be specified at the same time.
```

Or if I try to run a read with the query first:

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near the keyword &#39;SET&#39;.
```

This must be because it only supports SELECT statements.

Is it possible to do in Spark, or would I need to use a different connector and combine the setting of the *insert identity on*, together with regular *insert into* statements?

I would prefer a solution that allowed me to keep writing through the Spark context. But I am open to other solutions.

Comment: related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334012/cannot-insert-explicit-value-for-identity-column-in-table-table-when-identity. If you are using SQL Server, maybe you could try to set IDENTITY_INSERT ON

Comment: I have tried but as far as I can tell IDENTITY_INSERT ON only applies for the session. If I run the query through SSMS and then run my write command in spark I get the same error.

Comment: I think you should execute the command `SET IDENTITY_INSERT tableName ON` on  SQL Server itself not in your Spark code

Comment: That also does not work, I already try this and I get the same error when running my Spark code. As I mentioned in my previous comment, I ran the query in SSMS (SQL Server Management Studio), so on the SQL Server itself.

Comment: @Cralle did you find any solution for this issue, I am facing similar problem while trying to insert into a timestamp with default value. I set the identity as ON in SSMS but stil keep getting the error.

Comment: @NMAK No solution yet sadly. This issue is still relevant.

Answer (score 0):

One way to work around this issue is the following:

- Save your dataframe as a temporary table in your database.
- Set identity insert to ON.
- Insert into your real table the content of your temporary table.
- Set identity insert to OFF.
- Drop your temporary table.

Here's a pseudo code example:

```
tablename = "MyTable"
tmp_tablename = tablename+"tmp"
df.write.format("jdbc").options(..., dtable=tmp_tablename).save()
columns = ','.join(df.columns)
query = f"""
  SET IDENTITY_INSERT {tablename} ON;
  INSERT INTO {tablename} ({columns})
  SELECT {columns} FROM {tmp_tablename};
  SET IDENTITY_INSERT {tablename} OFF;
  DROP TABLE {tmp_tablename};
"""
execute(query) # You can use Cursor from pyodbc for example to execute raw SQL queries
```