# Hibernate throws exception when trying to persist entity

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have an entity "EntityA" that has the following id definition

```
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "sequence")
  @SequenceGenerator(name = "sequence", sequenceName = "sequence", allocationSize = 1)
  private Long id;
```

When trying to persist a new entry, the following logs appear:

```
Hibernate: select next value for sequence
Hibernate: insert into dbo.entityA (field1, field2, id) values (?,?,?)
Caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'entityA' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.
```

Table definition

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID('dbo.entityA') AND type = 'SO')
BEGIN
CREATE SEQUENCE sequence
    AS BIGINT
    START WITH 1
    INCREMENT BY 1
    MINVALUE 1
    NO MAXVALUE
    CACHE 1000;
END
GO

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.entityA') AND type in (N'U'))
BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE dbo.entityA(
        id BIGINT NOT NULL CONSTRAINT PK_id PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT (NEXT VALUE FOR sequence),
        field1 varchar(20) not null,
        field2 varchar(20) not null
    );
END
```

Persisting is a very basic creation, without me setting the id

```
EntityA entityA = new EntityA();
entityA.setField1("test");
entityA.setField2("test);
entityARepository.save(entityA);
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: @Jens please read before writing. thank you

Comment: @2dor that is the advice you should have taken. Jens is right in asking this question

Comment: `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "sequence")` wil generate the id

Comment: @2dor BTW: I read before writing

Comment: @2dor I know in the bit of code you've posted, you only set the field values, but if you look at the error message: "insert into dbo.entityA (field1, field2, id) values (?,?,?)" you can clearly see that that is not the only part being persisted

Comment: @Jens if you suggest removing the generated value annotation, this would not work because then I would get "ids for this class must be manually assigned before calling save()". I've already played with that, also changing the strategy to Identity

Comment: @2dor I do not suggest to remove it. I only got you a hint where the id comes from. I would suggest set `IDENTITY_INSERT` to `ON`

Comment: @Jens that is bad practice and I can't set the identity insert to on. something else must be wrong in what I'm doing

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'table' when IDENTITY\_INSERT is set to OFF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334012/cannot-insert-explicit-value-for-identity-column-in-table-table-when-identity)

Comment: @ArunSudhakaran no as I do not set value for id

Comment: @2dor as it is explained above, you do, just not manually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically have the id generation duplicated.

Your Hibernate mapping tells it to get a new id from a sequence an then use that in the insert statement.

But your table definition tries to create the id itself on insert.

So you should either adjust your Hibernate mapping to not generate an id explicitly, but to rely on the database to do that.
Or you should remove the `DEFAULT (NEXT VALUE FOR sequence)` part from your column declaration in the database.